# Where is sysxlogins in Management Studio?

Tags: sql, ssms

During the script processing I have this error:

> "Supplied parameter sid is in use."

I've heard that all logins and passwords are stored in sysxlogins table, where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking about `ms sql server` then its in `master` database. Actually its not table but view and its calles `sys.syslogins`

Comment: @Sergey - sys.syslogins will go away http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593.aspx and is replaced by sys.sql_logins and sys.server_principals http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx

Comment: Yeah, you're right but he didn't specify server version. View mensioned by me is from `sql server 2000` and stays in newer for backward compability.

Comment: @PiotrAuguscik - Well, he did not specify the version but since he can't find `sysxlogins` we do know that he is using SQL Server 2005 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [sys.sql_logins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174355.aspx) and [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx).